# Who invented the switch statement?

Tags: history

Switch statement is presented in all main languages today (Javascript, Java, PHP, C#, C++, C), but in what language this statement has for the first time appeared?

Comment: [Questions about programming history are off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255424/how-should-the-history-tag-be-disambiguated#comment24818_255425)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about history of programming and not programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lisp has `cond` which [Wikipedia's source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29#cite_note-35) places in the 1956-1958 timeframe.

> I invented conditional expressions in connection with a set of chess legal move routines I wrote in FORTRAN for the IBM 704 at M.I.T. during 1957-58...A paper defining conditional expressions and proposing their use in Algol was sent to the Communications of the ACM but was arbitrarily demoted to a letter to the editor, because it was very short.

-- [John McCarthy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McCarthy_%28computer_scientist%29): [Lisp Prehistory - Summer 1956 through Summer 1958](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/history/lisp/node2.html)

Comment: Right, forgot about the Lisp branch! Earlier than BCPL and ALGOL (although later than not-quite-yet-switch of FORTRAN). +1

Comment: I *think* the article would be in CACM volume 2 issue 8 (1959) but their on-line archive doesn't seem to include letters to the editor.  If anybody with access to old editions could verify this, or ideally, provide a link to the original, that would be grand.

Comment: The Wikipedia text alleges that this event is when `cond` was invented, but a cursory reading of the Lisp Prehistory article doesn't seem to verify or refute this claim.  Wikipedia alludes to a "more general *cond* structure" instead of just `if` - `then` - `else` so that's what I'm basing this answer on.

Answer (score 2):

It can't really be answered, as it was an evolution of a concept. C (the oldest in your list) was evolved from B (also had `switch`), which evolved from BCPL (had `switchon` statement). BCPL came from CPL, which (AFAIK) didn't. On the other side of the Pascal-vs-C canyon, ALGOL (had `case` statement in ALGOL68) evolved from FORTRAN (had a rudimentary predecessor in the computed `GO TO` statement). The computed `GO TO` is very low-level and easily implemented in assembly.

Comment: I ask about syntax, which is used in all popular languages. I believe too that it was B.

Answer (score 1):

Among the languages you're referring to, probably C would be the first. However, if you observe closely, the concept arises from more basic languages as in case of assembly level language,