# Why don't switch statements have curly braces?

Tags: javascript, java, c, syntax, switch-statement

The typical syntax for a switch-statement is:

```
switch(expression) {
  case one:
    // do something...
    break;
  case two:
    // do something else...
    break;
  case three:
  case four:
    // do something special
    break;
  default:
    // if nothing matches...
    break;
}
```

This syntax looks very Python-like (especially the colons and the way people indent it), contrary to the general syntax of languages such as JavaScript, Java, or C, where curly braces are used for most statements. Is there any specific reason?

I would expect that it should look more like:

```
switch(expression) {
  case (one) {
    // do something...
    break;
  } case (two) {
    // do something else...
    break;
  } case (three) case (four) {
    // do something special
    break;
  } default {
    // if nothing matches...
    break;
  }
}
```

I think the example I just provided looks like an if-else if-else statement, but shouldn't a switch statement match the syntax style?

Comment: @Pointy yes, but why is it optional?

Comment: Think of each `case` as a label for a `goto`. But there is no `goto`, instead the `switch` is jumping to the label.

Comment: C was the original they all inherited it from.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36394985/53897 for more details.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask why don't other languages look more like C ;-) BTW, just to confuse you further :-), you _can_ do: `switch (expression) { case one: { // do something } break; }`

Comment: C copied the syntax from an early version of BCPL. See [C history](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html).

Comment: When `switch` statement found matching case, every code below that case executed **until meet `break`**. Syntax what you suggest seems run only matching case.

Comment: Questions about why languages are the way they are **often** have useful answers. Languages don't spring out of nothingness, or by rolling dice. It is perfectly reasonable to ask why they are designed the way they are. Closing this as "not reproducible or caused by typos" is a misuse of the close system.

Comment: @zmag I'm just wondering about the _syntax_, not the functionality.

Comment: Why do 'if' statements have curly braces (in the general case) and not the much better if-then-elif-else-fi style?    Same answer: a liking for C syntax by Java designers.

Comment: I guess because they figured programmers would want fall-through. Of course, then there's the question of whether or not it causes more problems than it solves (accidental fall-through because one forgets to `break;`). The C# people thought so, so they only let you do it if you explicitly use `goto nextLabel;`.

Comment: @user16632363 Okay, Java likes C. Where did C get the idea from?

Comment: [The curious case of the switch statement](https://eev.ee/blog/2016/09/18/the-curious-case-of-the-switch-statement/)

Comment: You can really abuse a `switch` statement if you're creative.  Check out [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

Comment: A lot of things in C simply don't make sense and there is no rationale for them. `switch` statements in particular have a rather weird and brittle syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`case` statements are actually treated as labels in C, similar to those used by `goto`. Why it was designed like that is hard to answer and involves digging through various old publications by Dennis Ritchie.

More importantly for present day, you *can* use the `switch` with braces and it's even considered good practice. This is valid C (and C++):

```
switch(expression) 
{
  case one:
  {
    // do something...
    break;
  }
  case two:
  {
    // do something else...
    break;
  }
  case three:
  case four:
  {
    // do something special
    break;
  }
  default:
  {
    // if nothing matches...
    break;
  }
}
```

Now you can even declare local variables inside each case.

Answer (score 2):

In C-like programming languages, **an identifier with a colon** used as label to *jump*.

```c
label:   
// ...
goto label;
```

JavaScript doesn't have a `goto` statement but still has labels.

```js
label1: {
  label2: {
    console.log('break nested block');
    break label1;
    console.log('unreachable');
  }
  console.log('unreachable');
}
```

In `switch` statement, each `case` has a label for it. And `switch` statement has its own list for those labels called *jump table*. When given value is matching, *jump* to that label and execute every code follows like `goto`.